# Accepted App store game crash on two iPhone 4, version 4.3.3

Tags: ios, crash, app-store

Just released my first iOS game on Apple Appstore. (It is accepted by Apple)

It has worked fine a iPod (4th gen), a Iphone 3Gs and iPad 2/3.

However, two of my friends bought it on a iPhone 4, with iOS version 4.3.3 and they both say that it wont start. It quickly turns black then returns to the home screen.

Have no possibility to borrow their phones at the moment, and Googles search wont help me. Any ideas? Have no crash reports on iTunes Connect yet either.

The game has support for 4.1 an up. I have now temporary removed it from app store.

If someone got hockeyapp please try it out: https://rink.hockeyapp.net/recruit/baf90d07e6864bdfb2855a75b1a1877d

Borrowed a phone from one of my friends today, and tried to run the game (release version) from Xcode. It blacked out just like before, generating the following error in xcode:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-
hkwbdotvymdyljavlnsmbygluhnu/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/xxx.app/xxx'
-- failed to get the task for process 1585
```

But if you later just clicked the game icon on the iPhone, it ran perfectly...

The debug target/version did however work just fine.

**Update:**

If someone out there got iOS 4.3.3 please use one of these promo codes and try it out. If you are able please send a crash report if it crases.

```
JWF3LLP3ALMT
9M6XLTYY7TJ9
LWMKW7MTN99W
```

Comment: Have you tested it with iOS 4.3.3 on the iPhone Simulator? Did your test devices all have other versions of iOS than 4.3.3?

Comment: It works on all versions i have found in the simulator. 4.3.2 is the closest I have found. Both retina and normal. None of my own hardware have 4.3.3.

Comment: game still shows up in appstore: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/polar-defense-full/id537653791?mt=8

Comment: Yes, seems like only 3-4% use iOS 4.3.3 and the purchases of my friend did not come up on my stats so decided to keep it on App Store for now. If some one got a 4.3.3, please use one of the promo codes above and try it out!

Comment: i used LWMKW7MTN99W and now i am downloading your game on my ipad (iOS 4.3.3).

Comment: Do you know if you can extract any crash report?

Comment: Sorry. it is not worked. i will send you my logs if i can access.

Comment: it is your report. https://gist.github.com/3190530

Comment: Maybe GKNotificationBanner may not in your compile source

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, seems to be related to GKNotificationBanner.. Weird that it works for all versions but iOS 4.3.3 in release mode.

Comment: i change the gist with https://gist.github.com/3190671 . i removed your application name from gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crash Report :

```
Identifier:      appName
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-28 00:14:50.460 +0300
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J3)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GKNotificationBanner
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/...../appName.app/appName
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/GameKit
 in /var/mobile/Applications/...../appName.app/appName
  Dyld Version: 191.3
```

GKNotificationBanner is for iOS 5.0 and later

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKNotificationBanner_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks! Wierd, cause it passes App Store's inspection and it works on all simulators.

Comment: i think, Apple don't care your application work or not work. I dont understand what are they thinking, when they eliminate our application. But you can change your requirements for your application to not reduce your rating. if i can test GKNotificationBanner, i will write results, here.

Comment: I opened a new question for the rest of the problem, and posted some code related to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696173/gknotificationbanner-on-ios-4-3-and-up Please continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

Have your friends send you their crash reports. As soon as they sync they're phones, the crash reports will be copied to their computers (~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice on a Mac) and they can send them to you.

Comment: Borrowed one of my friends phones for 20 min today. Forgot to search for the crashlog, but can now afterwards see a lot of crash logs in Organizer > Devices > his device > Device Logs. Are these the same? In that case, he got no crashlog from my game..