# GKNotificationBanner on iOS 4.3.3

Tags: ios, ios5, crash, app-store

I am using the framework GKAchievementNotification (https://github.com/typeoneerror/GKAchievementNotification) in my iOS 4.1+ app. This app is approved by Apple (is on app store) but seems to crash on iOS 4.3.3. The crash log is the following:

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J3)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GKNotificationBanner
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/08289A0B-7AD3-4E37-B29F-A EDFE97B7ACA/PolarDefense.app/PolarDefense
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/GameKit.framework/GameKit
  in /var/mobile/Applications/08289A0B-7AD3-4E37-B29F-AEDFE97B7ACA/PolarDefense.app/PolarDefense
  Dyld Version: 191.3
```

Seems like the framework is not correctly discarding GKNotificationBanner for iOS versions which it does not support (iOS prior to 5.0).

I am assuming the error lies in the following code, what do you think it wrong?

```
@implementation GKAchievementHandler(private)
- (void)displayNotification:(GKAchievementNotification *)notification {
 #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 50000
  if ([GKNotificationBanner class]) {
    [GKNotificationBanner showBannerWithTitle:notification.title 
                                      message:notification.message
                            completionHandler:^{
                                [self didHideAchievementNotification:notification];
                            }
     ];
  } else
 #endif
  {
    [_topView addSubview:notification];
    [notification animateIn];
  }
}
@end
```

GKNotificationBanner is referensed in a few more places but always surrounded by #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 50000

So how come it crashes? (And why only in release mode?)

Deployment target is 4.1. I read now that the run-time checking of if a class exist is only supported in 4.2. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it could be related to me having a required linking to GameKit. Will change it to weak and submit it to App Store (for the third time).

Answer (score 2):

The `#if` statement will be resolved at compile time and not at runtime and checks for the Base SDK version instead of the deployment version too. Since you are building with the latest iOS version, this code will always be executed, not matter which iOS version it is running on.

You can check the availability at runtime like:

```
id GKNotificationBannerClass = NSClassFromString(@"GKNotificationBanner");
if (GKNotificationBannerClass) {
....
```

Comment: What's the difference between that and the class message sent in my example?

Comment: You are referencing the "real" class, which causes Dyld to load it, but it doesn't exist, therefore it crashes. `NSClassFromString` returns the class object named by the string, or nil if no class by that name is currently loaded.

Comment: ok, thanks, will try it. It's weird though that the debug version worked fine but when released to app store it crashes. So I have no way of testing that it works other than releasing a new version, wait 8-10 days for it to land on app store and then try it out. Will mark this answer as correct if it works.

Comment: Did you test on a device with iOS 4.3? That should crash with your implementation no matter what kind of configuration you are using to build.

Comment: Yes tried it on a 4.3.3 device. Running the debug version worked fine.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not correct. Changed all occurrences of GKNotificationBanner to your code. Released it to App Store. Still the exact same crash log as before. It still works in Debug Mode however. Tested on a 3Gs with iOS 4.3.5.

Comment: I am very very sure that my suggested way works and is the correct way to do it, since not only I am doing it all the time. Also my explanation of `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED ` is correct. Just one more example doing the same: https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController/blob/master/DETweetComposeViewController/UIDevice%2BDETweetComposeViewController.m#L24 Whatever you are doing when building for release breaks it. How does your updated code look? Did you try to build for release and test it on the device? What is different? There is no need to send it to Apple and wait.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html especially "Optionally Supporting Game Center In Your Game". Same test, but uses another GameKit class, also make sure to weak link GameKit, which I guess is not done. And make sure to test a release build before sending to Apple again!

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to weak link GameKit. Think that was the problem.

Comment: Well, than that was your second problem. If still do the #ifdef it will crash again.